# How to combine discrete and continous data in one Matlab Plot?

Tags: matlab, heatmap

I would like to display a matrix with values in a heatmap. The matrix contains discrete values, for example 100, 700, 900, which stand for z, x, p, etc. The matrix also contains values that are represented on a continuous scale (abc [mm]), such as values from 20 to 80 [mm]. I have already solved the problem in R. Unfortunately, I could not find an approach on how to implement the same heatmap as in the attached plot in Matlab.

[image: 1]

I have successfully plotted an imagsc plot with only discrete values and a heatmap with continuous values, but I have not successfully combined the two.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. We're going to need a sample of your data and a mapping function from the data to your plot. Without those, we'd be only guessing. [Edit] the post with a [mre].

Comment: You'll probably have to `hold on` and do a few `surf` (or other 3D) plots, using `NaN` to mask out the bits you want to "see through" to the other surfaces